# Javascript - Add Event Listener to live <a> tags but exclude the inside elements from the Event Listener

Tags: javascript

I have some `<a>` tags which are dynamically created and inside the `<a>` tags I have added Font Awesome Icons. So the HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> One</li>
    <li><a><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> Two</li>
</ul>
```

So now I want to toggle a class when clicking on the `<a>` tags. Since they are live elements, I have to add Event Listener to `<body>` or the parent element. But `event.target` is always showing the `<i>` tag whenever I click on the `<a>` tag. And this gives me trouble and I have to write a lot more code to select the `<a>` tag. I think this makes my code messy and isn't a proper way.

**How can I solve the problem?**

Comment: **But event.target is always coming the tag whenever I click on the tag.** what does this mean?

Comment: Use `event.currentTarget` instead. Or the `this` value.

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry for mistake @brk

Comment: "*I have to write a lot more code to select the `<a>` tag*" - can you show that code? It shouldn't be a lot, but yes using event delegation is non-trivial.

Comment: These text `One` & `Two` will be outside the anchor tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.target` returns the element that is deepest in the tree. Since `<i>` is inside `<a>` it is returned as a current target. To fix this you can use `Element.closest()` to get to the proper element.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
 const aEl = event.target.closest("a");
  if (aEl) {
   aEl.classList.toggle("active")
  }
})
```

```css
a {
  color: brown;
}

.active {
  color: mediumseagreen;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
    <li><a><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> One</li>
    <li><a><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> Two</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `Jquery` for this

```
$("body").on('click','a tag selector',function(){

console.log('clicked')

});
```

**Update 1**

for vanilla :

```
 document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.id== 'id of a tag'){
      console.log('clicked') ;
      }
 })
```

for details information search: DOM Event delegation

Comment: My project is in Angular and I am not allowed to use Jquery

Comment: it's just a choice using JQuery on angular project. I edited My anwser for vanilla

Answer (score 0):

> I Think This Will Help

```
//Keep This In A Function And Attach It To A Onclick() Method
  document.addEventListener("here_goes_the_id", function(){
    // The Things You Want To Do Go Here
    });
```

Comment: no it wont , because there is no id and you cannot pick every id & individually attach event to it

Comment: Also they are live elements. So I think we can't add Event Listener directly to them